# c# .Net EF CodeFirst: Como guardar un dato foreingkey de un combobox - error de conversión o tipo de dato

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, combobox, code-first

Tengo mi entidad Usuario en cual tiene los siguientes datos:

```
    public class Usuario
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Apellido { get; set; }
            public string DNI { get; set; }
            public int Edad { get; set; }
            public string Genero { get; set; }
            public int Celular { get; set; }
            public string Direccion { get; set; }
            public int Monto_Inicial { get; set; }
            public string Hora { get; set; }
            public DateTime Fecha_Ingreso { get; set; }
            public int? Grupo_Id { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("Grupo_Id")]
            public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
            public virtual Referido Referido { get; set; }
    }
```

Para agregar en la parte de mi regla de negocio(UsuarioRN) el código es la siguiente:

```
    public void Agregar(Usuario usuario)
    {
                contexto = new Contexto_SGlobalMoneyB_DB();
                contexto.usuarios.Add(usuario);
                contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Esta regla de negocio tiene su respectiva interface(IUsuario) porsiacaso lo pongo

```
    public interface IUsuario
    {
           void Agregar(Usuario usuario);
    }
```

Y por ultimo el código que uso para guardar en mi botón es el siguiente:

```
    usuarioRN = new UsuarioRN();
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario
    {
             Nombre = Tbx_Nombre.Text,
             Apellido = textBox1.Text,
             DNI = textBox2.Text,
             Edad = int.Parse(textBox3.Text),
             Genero = textBox4.Text,
             Celular = int.Parse(textBox5.Text),
             Direccion = textBox8.Text,
             Monto_Inicial = int.Parse(textBox9.Text),
             Fecha_Ingreso = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date,
             Hora = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
             Grupo_Id = int.Parse(comboBox2.Text),
    };
    usuarioRN.Agregar(usuario);
    MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");
```

El error esta al momento de guardar la llave foránea es Grupo_Id el cual deberia de guardar el id del grupo, pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo, ya intente con selectvalue pero tampoco quiere guardar, alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Que estas usando Winforms, asp net? o que

Comment: Estoy usando Windows forms

Comment: y como estas rellenando tu combo box?

Comment: De la siguiente manera 

       DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
        fila["Nombre"] = "SELECCIONE UNA OPCION";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        comboBox2.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el objeto seleccionado en el **combobox** de los grupos debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var grupo = (Grupo)grupoComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Aquí lo que se hace es castear el objeto seleccionado en el **combobox** de los grupos a su tipo correspondiente que seria un objeto de la **clase Grupo**.

Una vez hecho esto puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
usuarioRN = new UsuarioRN();

Usuario usuario = new Usuario
{
         Nombre = Tbx_Nombre.Text,
         Apellido = textBox1.Text,
         DNI = textBox2.Text,
         Edad = int.Parse(textBox3.Text),
         Genero = textBox4.Text,
         Celular = int.Parse(textBox5.Text),
         Direccion = textBox8.Text,
         Monto_Inicial = int.Parse(textBox9.Text),
         Fecha_Ingreso = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date,
         Hora = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
         Grupo = grupo
};

usuarioRN.Agregar(usuario);
MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");
```

Como ves aquí al construir el **objeto Usuario** le asignamos a su **propiedad Grupo**, el valor almacenado en la variable grupo antes explicado.

Comment: El error que ahora me bota es el siguiente : System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo 'SGlobalMoneyB.Core.Entidades.Grupo'.'

Comment: @Frans Estas usando entityframework?

Comment: Si, estoy usando la versión 6.4

Comment: @Frans Donde esta ese combobox, dentro del mismo grid? o lo tienes como un combobox independiente

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130182/japv entra aqui @Frans

Comment: no tengo 20 de reputación para hablar ahi

Comment: @Frans, ponme una foto de tu interfaz de usuario donde se vea el combo

Comment: lo subi https://ibb.co/qxvh5mq

Comment: @Frans y como llenas el combo

Comment: No uso las entidades pero lo lleno asi:
...
public void cargar_grupos()
{
          con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Grupoes", con);
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);
          con.Close();
          DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
          fila["Nombre"] = "SELECCIONE UNA OPCION";
          dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);
          comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
          comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
          comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
}
...

Comment: @Frans, si haces eso no estas usando entonces entityframework, estas trabajando directamente con sql y el código q te doy no funcionara, si usas el entityframework es para todo, no para un pedazo de tu proyecto. La decisión es tuya o usas entityframework o no lo usas, tu eliges

Comment: como llamaria los datos de la entidad Grupo en el combobox con EF para obtener el campo Id y Nombre

Answer (score 0):

Después de castear el objeto Grupo, lo único que me faltaba era obtener los datos en el comboBox mediante EF, y lo hice de la siguiente manera creando el siguiente método.

```
    public void cargarGrupo()
    {
        using (Contexto_SGlobalMoneyB_DB db = new Contexto_SGlobalMoneyB_DB())
        {
            var listagrupo = (from d in db.grupos select d).ToList();
            comboGrupo.DataSource = listagrupo;

            comboGrupo.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
            comboGrupo.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
    }
```

Después se tiene que llamar el método para que se inicie, lo puse en la parte donde se inicia los métodos ni bien se ejecuta el formulario.

```
    public frm_usuarios_mnt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cargarGrupo();
    }
```

Comment: Que bueno q te sirvio!!

Comment: Ahora tengo un problema, en vez de solo guardar crea un nuevo grupo con el siguiente id

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir, da mas detalles

Comment: Cuando hago click al botón agregar aparte de crear un nuevo usuario crea un nuevo grupo con los datos del grupo seleccionado.

Comment: Cual es el codigo del boton agregar?

Comment: el ultimo fragmento de código de la pregunta que termina con MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");